# show and hide element in table by js

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 tr ,table,td
{
border:black solid 1px;
text-align:center;
}
table
{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
#ab
{
background-color:cyan;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
<tbody>
<tr id='ab'>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>work</th>  
    <th>payment</th>
  </tr>  
<tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>  
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>  
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>  
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr id='ab'>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>work</th>  
    <th>payment</th>
  </tr>  
<tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>  
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>  
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>  
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr id='ab'>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>work</th>  
    <th>payment</th>
  </tr>  
<tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>  
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>  
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>  
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr id='ab'>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>work</th>  
    <th>payment</th>
  </tr>  
<tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>  
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>  
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>  
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr id='ab'>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>work</th>  
    <th>payment</th>
  </tr>  
<tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>  
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>  
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>  
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
<script >
  

 

</script>

</html>
```

i want slect only those rows(`<tr>`) whose element type is `<th>` and find parentelement and hide content[`<td>`]
how i an improve this

```
prop = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
a = prop[0].parentNode.parentNode.children;
for(var i=1;i<a.length;i++){
   a[i].style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: it's a bad practice to give multiple elements same `id`. Use `class` instead.

Comment: Using `JQuery` , you can do it with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Bind onclick event with every table row and hide/show the parent tbody when onclick is fired.

```
var tableSection = document.getElementsByClassName("ab");

for(var i = 0; i < tableSection.length; i++){
    tableSection[i].onclick = function(){
        var tbody = this.parentNode;
        for(var j = 1; j < (tbody.childNodes.length/3) + 1; j++){
            var status = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[j].style.display;
            if(status == "" || status == "block"){
                tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[j].style.display = 'none';
            } else{
                tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[j].style.display = '';
            }
        }
    };    
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/1b5bqyaL/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class='tblinfo' style="width: 100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>work</th>
        <th>payment</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I think what you wanted to do is above html code. If you are using table,th element(elements you want to show as header) should be inside thead and everything others inside tbody element.

And to select th element of table, below is the code:

```
$('.tblinfo thead tr th').addClass('tablehead');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
props=document.getElementsBytagName('td');
for(var i in props)
{
props[i].style.display="none";
}*/
prop=document.getElementsByTagName("th");
for(var i in prop)
{
prop[i].onclick=b;
}

function b()
{
 a= this.parentNode.parentNode.children;
 if(a[1].style.display=="")
 {
  for(var i=1;i<a.length;i++)
   {
    a[i].style.display="none";
   }

 }
 else
 {
 for(var i=1;i<a.length;i++)
   {
    a[i].style.display="";
   }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 
prop=document.getElementsByTagName("th");
for(var i in prop)
{
  prop[i].onclick=b;
}

function b()
{
 a= this.parentNode.parentNode.children;
 
    if(a[1].style.display=="")
 {
      for(var i=1;i<a.length;i++)
    {
    a[i].style.display="none";
   }

 }
 else
 {
         for(var i=1;i<a.length;i++)
   {
    a[i].style.display="";
   }

 }
}
```